# Turning (String, Base) into a float

Tags: python-3.x

```py
def eval_strfrac(s, base=2):  
    answer = 0 
    if '.' in s: 
        lst = s.split('.')
        seg1 = lst[0]
        seg2 = lst[1]
        power = len(seg1) - 1 
        for num in seg1: 
            if num.isalpha():
                answer += ((ord(num) - ord('a')) + 10) * (base**power)
            else:
                answer += int(num) * (base**power)
            power -= 1
        for num in seg2:
            if num.isalpha():
                answer += ((ord(num) - ord('a')) + 10) * (base**power)
                
            else:
                answer += int(num) * (base**power)
            power -= 1
            print(answer)
    else:
        return float(int(s, base))

print(f"eval_strfrac('mxffdw.m6djs', base=35) -> {eval_strfrac('mxffdw.m6djs', base=35)}")
```

The above returns eval_strfrac('mxffdw.m6djs', base=35) -> 1205663862.633786
but I'm supposed to get 1205663862.6337857.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: look the same to me. You can only get about 16 digits of decimal precision with a 64 bit float

Comment: Just looks like rounding error to me. ps, you need to `return answer` in the truthy part of if branch.

Comment: This is actually the reason numbers would ever be stored as strings, or a BigDecimal format, or similar. You just don't get infinite precision with a float type

Comment: in this particular case, you can use `decimal` instead of `float`. You can set your precision if using `decimal`